# how do I set max clients in apache 2.4.4?

Tags: wamp

How do I set MaxClients and MaxChildRequests in Apache 2.4.4 (Wamp). I can not find anything in the httpd.conf file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

For those arriving via search-engines (like I did) I found it on /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf

Answer (score 0):

Is this documentation any help

[MAXREQUESTWORKERS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers)

and possibly [ThreadsPerChild](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#threadsperchild)

RE: Your comment.

If y ou are actually using WAMPServer then you use the wampmanager menus to edit the correct files. Wampmanager is the icon that sits in the `system tray` normally thats in the bottom right corner of the screen.

So left click the wampmanager icon to show the menu and then follow these menu names.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Comment: I actually want to know which file I can edit to set the max clients etc, I can not find anything in the httpd.conf file.